# Unable to Find Steam UMQID for Chat Message

Tags: javascript, go, steam

Using Golang, I am trying to send a chat message through [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/chat). The requirements for the post are

- `jsonp: jQuery1111021217753615295387_1460262983441` *<- I am able to get this one*
- `umqid: 6271781725479270872` **<- I am unable to understand what this is and how to retreive it.**
- `type: saytext` *<- I am able to get this one*
- `steamid_dst: 76561198208696745` *<- I am able to get this one*
- `text: foobar` *<- I am able to get this one*
- `access_token: 87e689c612b38f535a4d2b645b3aa3a7` *<- I am able to get this one*
- `_: 1460262983442` *<- I am able to get this one*

I understand all the variables required and am able to use them except for the UMQID variable. I have been through [Steam's javascript source code](https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/javascript/chat.js?v=CO5oN56q_gcZ&l=english) over and over trying to figure out what the value of it is and how they generate the value but I haven't managed to understand it.

I've even been through [someone else's Golang source code](https://github.com/Zemnmez/geothermal/blob/master/chat/chat.go) *(line 211)* which does exactly what I am aiming for but I still can't even figure out how they got the UMQID.

If anyone could explain how I am able to get the UMQID so I can post https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebUserPresenceOAuth/Message/v0001/ to send a Steam message, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see he's decoding it by making a call to https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebUserPresenceOAuth/Logon/v0001/  at https://github.com/Zemnmez/geothermal/blob/master/chat/chat.go#L158

Comment: 3rd time you've answered a question about golang for me lol, thanks heaps!